# Player vs computer

Tags: ruby

Created this connect 4 game following a guide online but the guide didn't explain how to make it computer vs player it only explained how to make it player vs player. I've tried adding a computer variable that generated a random number 1..8 for the columns but it wasn't working was just sitting there asking player two to pick a location.

Here's the player code below how do i implement player vs computer ?

```
class Board
  attr_accessor :board
  attr_reader :turn, :identifier

  def initialize
    @board = [
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    ]
    @turn = 0
    @identifier = 1
  end

  def choose_column(col)
    7.downto(0) do |i|
      if board[i][col-1] == 0
        board[i][col-1] = identifier
        break
      end
    end
    false
  end

  def win?
    return true if check_rows?
    return true if check_columns?
    return true if check_diagonal?
  end

  def check_validity(sum,num)
    if num == 1
      sum = 0 if sum < 0
      sum += 1
    elsif num == -1
      sum = 0 if sum > 0
      sum -= 1
    else
      sum = 0
    end
  end

  def check_rows?
    8.times do |i|
      board[i].inject(0) do |sum, num|
        sum = check_validity(sum,num)
        return true if sum.abs == 4
        sum
      end
    end
    false
  end

  def check_columns?
    8.times do |i|
      column = []
      board.each { |row| column.push(row[i]) }
      column.inject(0) do |sum, num|
        sum = check_validity(sum,num)
        return true if sum.abs == 4
        sum
      end
    end
    false
  end

  def check_diagonal?
    board[0..2].each_with_index do |row, row_i|
      row.each_with_index do |column, col_i|
        if col_i <=3
          sum = board[row_i][col_i]
          1.upto(3) { |i| sum += board[row_i+i][col_i+i] }
          return true if sum.abs == 4
        end
        if col_i >= 3
          sum = board[row_i][col_i]
          1.upto(3) { |i| sum += board[row_i+i][col_i-i] }
          return true if sum.abs == 4
        end
      end
    end
    false
  end

  def new_game
    @turn = 1
  end

  def game_flow
    new_game
    while turn < 43
      assign_player
      player = @identifier == 1 ? 1 : 2
      puts draw_board
      print "Round #{@turn}. Player #{player}'s turn. Choose column (1-8): "
      input = gets.chomp
      while !validate_input(input) || check_full?(input)
        print "Invalid Pick. Try again: "
        input = gets.chomp
      end
      input = validate_input(input)
      choose_column(input)
      if win?
        puts draw_board
        puts "Congratulations. Player #{player} won"
        break
      end
      @turn += 1
    end
    puts "Draw!" unless win?
    return true
  end

  def assign_player
    @identifier = @turn.odd? ? 1 : -1
  end

  def validate_input(input)
    return input !~ /^[1-8]$/ ? false : input.to_i
  end

  def check_full?(column)
    column = column.to_i
    column -= 1
    return board[0][column] != 0
  end

  def draw_board
    print "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8\n"
    rep = { 0 => ".", 1 => "O", -1 => "X" }
    board.each do |row|
      print  "#{rep[row[0]]} #{rep[row[1]]} #{rep[row[2]]} #{rep[row[3]]} #{rep[row[4]]} #{rep[row[5]]} #{rep[row[6]]} #{rep[row[7]]}\n"
    end
    print " "
  end
end

board = Board.new
board.game_flow
```

Comment: Clearly if you're replacing player two with the computer player, it shouldn't even get to the code that asks player two for input.

Comment: That's true, its like i stated above, i tried to edit the code to have the computer play i edited the identifier to only identifies player 1 and added the variable and i had it generate a 1..8 but it wasn't working it continued to as for player 2 even though i removed player 2.

Comment: It can't *continue to as for player 2* if you removed player 2. Therefore, you clearly did not completely remove player 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Ken White says, if you want the computer to select a choice, you need to detect when it is the computer's turn. It looks like in your example this is encoded in the `@player` variable. You can have a simple `if` branch which only prompts for input when it is the human player's turn. Everything else could remain the same, but you would update your `game_flow` method to consider this other case:

```
if player == 1
  print "Round #{@turn}. Player #{player}'s turn. Choose column (1-8): "
  input = gets.chomp
  while !validate_input(input) || check_full?(input)
    print "Invalid Pick. Try again: "
    input = gets.chomp
  end
  input = validate_input(input)
else
  input = rand(1..8)
end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: My question now is when i edit it for this to work now, Now when i connect 4 the forth one wont display but it states the player won only showing 3 instead of 4